# Python-Flask not accepting custom fonts

Tags: python, flask

Folder Blueprint

Templates

- File.html

Static

- Fonts
- Style

In the css file , i tried :

```
@font-face{
font-family:<Font_name>
src:{{ url_for('static',filename='fonts/<font_name>.ttf') }} ;
}
```

What changes are to be made to add custom fonts ?

Comment: Thank you for your (IMHO) very well-written question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use template tags in css. the Jinja template tags are only meant for html files and templates not css.

To use a css file, you have to insert the link manually there, something along the lines of:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: customfont;
    src: /static/Fonts/font.ttf';
}
```

The only way to get around this is to serve a template, that contains the css embedded in `<style></style>` tags that way flask would be able to interprete the template tags. so with that you should have something like this

```
<style>
@font-face{
    font-family: <Font_name>
    src: {{ url_for('static',filename='fonts/<font_name>.ttf') }} ;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your project directory is setup such (Arrows = level of directories):
~/ 
 >static/
 >>fonts/
 >>>MyFont.woff
 >templates/
 >>index.html
 >main.py

the following implementation of a fontface in your index.html's style tag should work:

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <style>
         @font-face {
            font-family: "MyFont";
            src: url("/static/fonts/MyFont.woff");
        }
        </style>
    </head>
</html>
```